# Multiple sites on same server and issues with SSL

Tags: wordpress, ssl

A number of months ago I created the site cascocc.com. All is well. I then created another site coloradospringshomebuilders.com. All was well, I started development.

I then got an SSL for cascocc.com and installed it, all was well. Some items were not being delivered using SSL so I used the plug in force SSL to get the fancy green bar to show up.

Now coloradospringshomebuilders.com redirects to cascocc.com and I can not figure out how to fix it. I have reverted all my htacess files to the most basic possible. Am I missing one or what am I missing?

Any ideas?

EDIT: I deleted ALL .htaccess files on the entire server. The second site is still redirecting to the first and trying to use the firsts site SSL cert. I do not understand how this is happening

[1st sites .htaccess file](http://pastebin.com/q1B5qR0m)

[2nd sites .htaccess file](http://pastebin.com/fWQdZ3zU)

Comment: Are you defining virtual server configuration for each site? Otherwise, they will all fall back to the first site in alphabetical order (you need to specify ssl params for each site using ssl, redirect to 80 if it's not using ssl)

Comment: I have added the htaccess files for both sites.  I am not sure how to specify ssl parms, I will have to look into that

Comment: You need to edit your conf files for the virtual hosts. You will find them under apache (or nginx) folder. If you don't have access to web server configuration, contact your hostmaster

Answer (score 1):

This problem sounds like your Virtual hosts are not setup correctly. The SSL setting is overriding any other setting and redirecting to the page that is setup with SSL.

That can only be solved in the server settings (in this case most likely the virtual host). Depending on where you host your sites you might not have access to this, so I would advise to direct this question to your hosting provider.

This whole "redirect" is happening before the server reads the .htaccess files, that's why you can't solve this problem there.